# snowflake-connector: MissingDependencyError' issue with write_pandas function

Tags: python, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to ingest data into snowflake using Python geopandas and snowflake-connector library. Here is my code:

```
import geopandas
import pandas as pd
import json
import snowflake.connector
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas

snowflake_config = {
    'account': account_url,
    'warehouse':'wh_name',
    'database':'db_name',
    'schema':'schmea_name',
    'role': 'role_name'
}
shapefile=geopandas.read_file("path of shap file in zip format")
df = pd.DataFrame(shapefile)
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user = 'username',
    authenticator ='externalbrowser',
    **snowflake_config
)
create_table_query = f'''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_name.schema_name.TRIALEXAMPLE (
            globalid STRING,
            CreationDa date,
            EditDate date,
            your_name STRING,
            are_you_a_ STRING,
            which_indu STRING,
            COORDINATES varchar
            
        )
    '''

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(create_table_query)
success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(conn, df, 'TRIALEXAMPLE')
```

When I ran the program, it gave following error on the last command of the code:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(conn, df, 'TRIALEXAMPLE')

File ~\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\envs\snowflake-env\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\pandas_tools.py:271, in write_pandas(conn, df, table_name, database, schema, chunk_size, compression, on_error, parallel, quote_identifiers, auto_create_table, create_temp_table, overwrite, table_type, **kwargs)
    267 if chunk_size is None:
    268     chunk_size = len(df)
    270 if not (
--> 271     isinstance(df.index, pandas.RangeIndex)
    272     and 1 == df.index.step
    273     and 0 == df.index.start
    274 ):
    275     warnings.warn(
    276         f"Pandas Dataframe has non-standard index of type {str(type(df.index))} which will not be written."
    277         f" Consider changing the index to pd.RangeIndex(start=0,...,step=1) or "
   (...)
    280         stacklevel=2,
    281     )
    283 cursor = conn.cursor()

File ~\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\envs\snowflake-env\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\options.py:39, in MissingOptionalDependency.__getattr__(self, item)
     38 def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 39     raise errors.MissingDependencyError(self._dep_name)

AttributeError: module 'snowflake.connector.errors' has no attribute 'MissingDependencyError'
```

I made sure that I installed the latest version of snowflake-connector-python (i.e. 3.2.0) is installed. Any help would be appreciated to fix the issue.

Comment: If you manually open the file `~\AppData\Local\Anaconda3\envs\snowflake-env\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py` does it have a class called `MissingDependencyError`?

Comment: @Sergiu, Yes, it does have a class called MissingDependencyError